# Running multiple shell scripts without arguments in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I have many scripts in a directory that all start with `deploy_` (for instance, `deploy_example.com`).
I usually run them one at a time by calling `./deploy_example.com`.

How do I run them all, one after the other (or all at once if possible...)?

I've tried:

```
find deploy_* | xargs | bash
```

But that fails as it needs the absolute path if called like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performed in a subshell to prevent your current IFS and positional parameters from being lost.

```
( set -- ./deploy_*; IFS=';'; eval "$*" )
```

EDIT: That sequence broken down

```
(                     # start a subshell, a child process of your current shell

  set -- ./deploy_*   # set the positional parameters ($1,$2,...)
                      #   to hold your filenames

  IFS=';'             # set the Internal Field Separator

  echo "$*"           # "$*" (with the double quotes) forms a new string:
                      #   "$1c$2c$3c$4c..." 
                      #   joining the positional parameters with 'c',
                      #   the first character of $IFS

  eval "$*"           # this evaluates that string as a command, for example:
                      #    ./deploy_this;./deploy_that;./deploy_example.com
)
```

Comment: I've not seen this technique before. Any chance of a quick explanation of what's going on?

Comment: This is a really neat way to do this. Marking as accepted because I want other people to see this!

Comment: This assumes you don't have any stupid filenames, for example `"./deploy_\`rm -rf /\`"`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in several ways. For example, you can do:

```
for i in deploy_* ; do bash $i ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
for x in deploy*; do bash ./$x; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find deploy_* | xargs -n 1 bash -c
```

Will run them all one after the other. Look at the man page for `xargs` and the `--max-procs` setting to get some degree of parallelism.